# All data from first table is not showing in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-5.6

I am trying to add two tables, in which first table contains all the video details, and in second table details of video seen by the user with user_id and video_id. I just want to add both the tables and it will show all the list of videos from first table but if the video is seen by the user, status will show 1 else 1.

Here is my query,

```
SELECT
    videos.id, videos.lang_id, videos.medical_type_id, videos.name, 
    videos.description, videos.thumbnail, videos.video, videos.video_type, 
    videos.delete_status, 
    CASE 
       WHEN video_quews.user_id = $user_id 
          THEN $user_id 
          ELSE 'ok' 
    END AS user_id, 
    video_quews.video_id, video_quews.created_at, 
    CASE 
       WHEN video_quews.video_id = videos.id 
          THEN 1 
          ELSE 0 
    END AS status 
FROM
    videos 
LEFT JOIN 
    video_quews ON videos.id = video_quews.video_id 
ORDER BY   
    video_quews.video_id DESC
```

Currently, videos are repeating.

Please help me out

here is my response,

```
{
    "message": "All related videos",
    "status": "success",
    "code": 200,
    "videos": [
        {
            "id": "30",
            "lang_id": "2",
            "medical_type_id": "15",
            "name": "Fracture",
            "thumbnail": "thumbnail_images/1579869167.png",
            "video": "videos/fracture.m4v",
            "video_type": "2",
            "delete_status": "1",
            "user_id": "6",
            "video_id": "30",
            "created_at": "2021-03-04 23:29:50",
            "status": "1"
        },
        {
            "id": "16",
            "lang_id": "2",
            "medical_type_id": "14",
            "name": "Electrocution",
            "thumbnail": "thumbnail_images/1579698529.png",
            "video": "videos/ELECTROCUTION.m4v",
            "video_type": "2",
            "delete_status": "1",
            "user_id": "ok",
            "video_id": "16",
            "created_at": "2021-03-05 08:19:29",
            "status": "1"
        },
        {
            "id": "15",
            "lang_id": "2",
            "medical_type_id": "13",
            "name": "Adult CPR & AED(Cardiac Arrest)",
            "thumbnail": "thumbnail_images/1579698505.png",
            "video": "videos/CPR1.mp4",
            "video_type": "2",
            "delete_status": "1",
            "user_id": "ok",
            "video_id": "15",
            "created_at": "2021-03-05 08:18:38",
            "status": "1"
        },
        {
            "id": "14",
            "lang_id": "2",
            "medical_type_id": "12",
            "name": "Choking",
            "thumbnail": "thumbnail_images/1579698405.png",
            "video": "videos/Choking.mp4",
            "video_type": "2",
            "delete_status": "1",
            "user_id": "ok",
            "video_id": "14",
            "created_at": "2021-03-05 08:17:47",
            "status": "1"
        },
        {
            "id": "13",
            "lang_id": "2",
            "medical_type_id": "11",
            "name": "Chest pain",
            "thumbnail": "thumbnail_images/1579698381.png",
            "video": "videos/CHESTPAIN.mp4",
            "video_type": "2",
            "delete_status": "1",
            "user_id": "ok",
            "video_id": "13",
            "created_at": "2021-03-05 08:17:20",
            "status": "1"
        },
        {
            "id": "12",
            "lang_id": "2",
            "medical_type_id": "10",
            "name": "Burns",
            "thumbnail": "thumbnail_images/1579698360.png",
            "video": "videos/Burns.mp4",
            "video_type": "2",
            "delete_status": "1",
            "user_id": "ok",
            "video_id": "12",
            "created_at": "2021-03-05 08:16:39",
            "status": "1"
        },
        {
            "id": "11",
            "lang_id": "2",
            "medical_type_id": "9",
            "name": "Breathing Difficulties",
            "thumbnail": "thumbnail_images/1579698344.png",
            "video": "videos/BreathingDifficulties.mp4",
            "video_type": "2",
            "delete_status": "1",
            "user_id": "ok",
            "video_id": "11",
            "created_at": "2021-03-05 08:16:19",
            "status": "1"
        },
        {
            "id": "8",
            "lang_id": "2",
            "medical_type_id": "6",
            "name": "Asthma",
            "thumbnail": "thumbnail_images/1579698286.png",
            "video": "videos/ASTHMA.mp4",
            "video_type": "2",
            "delete_status": "1",
            "user_id": "ok",
            "video_id": "8",
            "created_at": "2021-03-05 08:15:59",
            "status": "1"
        },
        {
            "id": "24",
            "lang_id": "2",
            "medical_type_id": "22",
            "name": "Fits/Seizures",
            "thumbnail": "thumbnail_images/1579698775.png",
            "video": "videos/SEIZURES.m4v",
            "video_type": "2",
            "delete_status": "1",
            "user_id": "ok",
            "video_id": null,
            "created_at": null,
            "status": "0"
        },
        {
            "id": "26",
            "lang_id": "2",
            "medical_type_id": "24",
            "name": "Sprain, strain",
            "thumbnail": "thumbnail_images/1579698853.png",
            "video": "videos/SPRAIN&STRAIN.mp4",
            "video_type": "2",
            "delete_status": "1",
            "user_id": "ok",
            "video_id": null,
            "created_at": null,
            "status": "0"
        },
        {
            "id": "28",
            "lang_id": "2",
            "medical_type_id": "26",
            "name": "Disposing Glove",
            "thumbnail": "thumbnail_images/1579698903.png",
            "video": "videos/disposingglove.mp4",
            "video_type": "1",
            "delete_status": "1",
            "user_id": "ok",
            "video_id": null,
            "created_at": null,
            "status": "0"
        },
        {
            "id": "31",
            "lang_id": "2",
            "medical_type_id": "8",
            "name": "Bleeding",
            "thumbnail": "thumbnail_images/1581498917.png",
            "video": "videos/bleeding.mp4",
            "video_type": "2",
            "delete_status": "1",
            "user_id": "ok",
            "video_id": null,
            "created_at": null,
            "status": "0"
        },
        {
            "id": "18",
            "lang_id": "2",
            "medical_type_id": "16",
            "name": "Gunshot Wound",
            "thumbnail": "thumbnail_images/1579698550.png",
            "video": "videos/Gunshot.mp4",
            "video_type": "2",
            "delete_status": "1",
            "user_id": "ok",
            "video_id": null,
            "created_at": null,
            "status": "0"
        },
        {
            "id": "20",
            "lang_id": "2",
            "medical_type_id": "18",
            "name": "Hypoglycemia",
            "thumbnail": "thumbnail_images/1579698684.png",
            "video": "videos/Hypoglycemia.mp4",
            "video_type": "2",
            "delete_status": "1",
            "user_id": "ok",
            "video_id": null,
            "created_at": null,
            "status": "0"
        },
        {
            "id": "22",
            "lang_id": "2",
            "medical_type_id": "20",
            "name": "Nose Bleeding",
            "thumbnail": "thumbnail_images/1579698728.png",
            "video": "videos/nosebleeding.mp4",
            "video_type": "2",
            "delete_status": "1",
            "user_id": "ok",
            "video_id": null,
            "created_at": null,
            "status": "0"
        },
        {
            "id": "25",
            "lang_id": "2",
            "medical_type_id": "23",
            "name": "Snake Bite",
            "thumbnail": "thumbnail_images/1579698801.png",
            "video": "videos/SnakeBite.mp4",
            "video_type": "2",
            "delete_status": "1",
            "user_id": "ok",
            "video_id": null,
            "created_at": null,
            "status": "0"
        },
        {
            "id": "27",
            "lang_id": "2",
            "medical_type_id": "25",
            "name": "Stroke",
            "thumbnail": "thumbnail_images/1579698879.png",
            "video": "videos/STROKE.m4v",
            "video_type": "2",
            "delete_status": "1",
            "user_id": "ok",
            "video_id": null,
            "created_at": null,
            "status": "0"
        },
        {
            "id": "29",
            "lang_id": "2",
            "medical_type_id": "27",
            "name": "Dog Bite",
            "thumbnail": "thumbnail_images/1579698934.png",
            "video": "videos/Dogbite.mp4",
            "video_type": "2",
            "delete_status": "1",
            "user_id": "ok",
            "video_id": null,
            "created_at": null,
            "status": "0"
        },
        {
            "id": "32",
            "lang_id": "2",
            "medical_type_id": "7",
            "name": "Allergy",
            "thumbnail": "thumbnail_images/1581580973.png",
            "video": "videos/Allergy.mp4",
            "video_type": "2",
            "delete_status": "1",
            "user_id": "ok",
            "video_id": null,
            "created_at": null,
            "status": "0"
        },
        {
            "id": "19",
            "lang_id": "2",
            "medical_type_id": "17",
            "name": "Hyperthermia(Heat Exhaustion)",
            "thumbnail": "thumbnail_images/1579698575.png",
            "video": "videos/Hyperthermia.mp4",
            "video_type": "2",
            "delete_status": "1",
            "user_id": "ok",
            "video_id": null,
            "created_at": null,
            "status": "0"
        },
        {
            "id": "21",
            "lang_id": "2",
            "medical_type_id": "19",
            "name": "Introduction",
            "thumbnail": "thumbnail_images/1579698707.png",
            "video": "videos/intro.mp4",
            "video_type": "1",
            "delete_status": "1",
            "user_id": "ok",
            "video_id": null,
            "created_at": null,
            "status": "0"
        },
        {
            "id": "23",
            "lang_id": "2",
            "medical_type_id": "21",
            "name": "Recovery Position",
            "thumbnail": "thumbnail_images/1579698747.png",
            "video": "videos/RecoveryPosition.mp4",
            "video_type": "2",
            "delete_status": "1",
            "user_id": "ok",
            "video_id": null,
            "created_at": null,
            "status": "0"
        }
    ],
}
```

Below is my database,
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QV9Gs.png)

Comment: Could you please share some sample data? This query should not loose any data from table videos.

Comment: in the last column, do you want count of no of user who seen a video or you just want 1 /0

Comment: i just want 1/0

Comment: and as your query shows that you want to username / 'ok' , do you want user detail in a single column like 'user1, user2, ok,....'  etc

Comment: its for testing, it may be null

Comment: I have added current output sample

Comment: I have updated the sample data

Comment: that is not help us, as your query always give muliple result of a video table, if there is muliple entry in video detail table. when you add as a left join and if there is record then first table will repeat with your second table

Comment: yes, in second table there is multiple entry of one video but always with different user_id

Comment: what is $ sign with $user_id, do you get any syntax error. Also what is your db, oracle /sqlserver /else?

Comment: $user_id contains the user_id value

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple rows for a video in video_ques table that's why you are getting duplicate items. Please clarify if there is multiple user in video_ques table for one video how you wanna represent those. I have changed the query to get first match from video_ques if there are multiple rows. Please check below query:

**For MYSQL version lower than 8:**

```
  SELECT
        videos.id, videos.lang_id, videos.medical_type_id, videos.name, 
        videos.description, videos.thumbnail, videos.video, videos.video_type, 
        videos.delete_status, 
        CASE 
           WHEN VQ.user_id = $user_id 
              THEN $user_id 
              ELSE 'ok' 
        END AS user_id, 
        VQ.video_id, VQ.created_at, 
        CASE 
           WHEN VQ.video_id = videos.id 
              THEN 1 
              ELSE 0 
        END AS status 
    FROM
        videos 
    LEFT JOIN 
        (SELECT * ,(SELECT COUNT(*)  FROM video_quews b WHERE a.video_id=b.video_id and a.user_id >= b.user_id) rn from video_quews a ) VQ ON videos.id = VQ.video_id and rn=1
    ORDER BY   
        VQ.video_id DESC
```

**For MySQL version 8 and higher:**

```
     with cte as (select * ,ROW_NUMBER()over(partition by video_id order by user_id)rn from video_quews )
SELECT
    videos.id, videos.lang_id, videos.medical_type_id, videos.name, 
    videos.description, videos.thumbnail, videos.video, videos.video_type, 
    videos.delete_status, 
    CASE 
       WHEN video_quews.user_id = $user_id 
          THEN $user_id 
          ELSE 'ok' 
    END AS user_id, 
    video_quews.video_id, video_quews.created_at, 
    CASE 
       WHEN video_quews.video_id = videos.id 
          THEN 1 
          ELSE 0 
    END AS status 
FROM
    videos 
LEFT JOIN 
    cte ON videos.id = video_quews.video_id and rn=1
ORDER BY   
    video_quews.video_id DESC
```

Comment: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'outer apply (select top(1) * from video_quews where

Comment: I have revised the answer for mysql. Sorry it was for sql server.

Comment: Which version of MySql are you using?

Comment: libmysql - 5.6.43

Comment: then this query wont work. let me change this

Comment: I have updated my answer. Since I don't have any sample data I couldn't check it. Please let me know your feedback.

Comment: @Bhawesh Please let me know whether your problem is resolved or not.

Comment: no, its still showing status 1 for all videos, and also user_id is always showing "ok"

Comment: Can u please send me input data at kmnur@hotmail.com?

Comment: I have above added my response can you please check